# Can you validate an NSManagedObject without saving?

Tags: core-data

Is it possible to some how determine if an `NSManagedObject` is valid, without actually saving?

Seems like there should be an `isValid` function, or some way to request the `NSManagedObjectContext` to run validation for a particular object without actually saving.

The only workaround I can think of is to pull the object into a temporary child context, "touch" it so that it will be treated as updated, and then try to save the child context. But that seems quite barbaric.

Comment: Have you seen the validation functions built into key value coding - see [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/ValidatingProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i-CH18-SW1)?  I think CoreData uses these automatically but no reason you can't trigger them manually.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed they were just for overriding and doing cross-property validation. Did not realize they trigger the property-based validation routines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `validateForInsert` or `validateForUpdate`.